# namespace::function cannot be used as a function

Tags: function, c++11, compiler-errors, namespaces, syntax-error

main.cpp

```
#include "Primes.h"
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::string choose;
    int num1, num2;
    while(1 == 1){
        std::cout << "INSTRUCTIONS" << std::endl << "Enter:" << std::endl
                  << "'c' to check whether a number is a prime," << std::endl
                  << "'u' to view all the prime numbers between two numbers "
                  << "that you want," << std::endl << "'x' to exit," 
                  << std::endl << "Enter what you would like to do: ";
        std::cin >> choose;
        std::cout << std::endl;
        if(choose == "c"){
            std::cout << "Enter number: ";
            std::cin >> num1;
            Primes::checkPrimeness(num1) == 1 ?
            std::cout << num1 << " is a prime." << std::endl << std::endl :
            std::cout << num1 << " isn't a prime." << std::endl << std::endl;
        }else if(choose == "u"){
            std::cout << "Enter the number you want to start seeing primes "
                      << "from: ";
            std::cin >> num1;
            std::cout << "\nEnter the number you want to stop seeing primes "
                      << "till: ";
            std::cin >> num2;
            std::cout << std::endl;
            for(num1; num1 <= num2; num1++){
                Primes::checkPrimeness(num1) == 1 ?
                std::cout << num1 << " is a prime." << std::endl :
                std::cout << num1 << " isn't a prime." << std::endl;
            }
        }else if(choose == "x"){
            return 0;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Primes.h

```
#ifndef PRIMES_H
#define PRIMES_H

namespace Primes{
    extern int num, count;
    extern bool testPrime;
    // Returns true if the number is a prime and false if it isn't.
    int checkPrimeness(num);
}

#endif
```

Primes.cpp

```
#include "Primes.h"
#include <iostream>

int Primes::checkPrimeness(num){
    if(num < 2){
        return(0);
    }else if(num == 2){
        return(1);
    }else{        
        for(count = 0; count < num; count++){
            for(count = 2; count < num; count++){
                if(num % count == 0){
                    return(0);
                }else{
                    testPrime = true;
                    if(count == --num && testPrime == true){
                        return(1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }    
    }
}
```

I get the following 3 errors: [Errors from terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0fY1.png)

I've spent hours for days and still can't seem to fix the errors.
I've tried using extern and pretty much everything I can imagine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an error in function declaration:

```
int checkPrimeness(num);
```

defines *a global integer variable **checkPrimeness** initialized with **num***! To declare a function you just should change it like:

```
int checkPrimeness(int);
```

Can't understand why you declare parameters as external variables. To split declarations and realization you should declare all functions and classes inside header file, and define them inside source file.

Comment: Thanks! I still have some errors though, I changed nothing in the main.cpp and changed "num" to "int" in both the Primes.h and Primes.cpp files. (I also saw that I had accidentally used count twice so I made a new "evaluate" variable for that). However, it's still telling me that there are multiple definitions for all my variables; and with just int as the formal parameter, how would I pass num's value via the actual argument? Would I have to put this in a class as this would be a member variable?